# angular.js without hashbang in non-html5 browsers

Tags: html, angularjs, browser-history, history.js

Has anyone managed to rid of hashbang urls for angular.js applications running in non-html5 browsers ?

I have an application targeting  IE8/9, and I would prefer not to have hashbang urls. So, looking to use html5 polyfills(history.js etc) with angular. Is it recommended approach ?